# I am getting error in WCF

Tags: wcf

Error:

> There was an error downloading
>   'https://mum-19377/memoqservices/SecurityService/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'. The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found. Metadata contains
>   a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'https://mum-19377/memoqservices/SecurityService'. There was no
>   endpoint listening at https://mum-19377/memoqservices/SecurityService
>   that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
>   details. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. If the
>   service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution
>   and adding the service reference again.

My Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CommonBindingConfig" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="16000000" maxBufferSize="4000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="4000000" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="0" maxStringContentLength="4000000" maxArrayLength="4000000" maxBytesPerRead="4000000" maxNameTableCharCount="0"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>



      <wsHttpBinding>

        <binding name="TransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>

          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>


    </bindings>

    <client>

      <endpoint address="http://mum-19377/memoqservices/Security/SecurityService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CommonBindingConfig" contract="SecurityService.ISecurityService" name="SecurityService"/>
      <endpoint address="http://mum-19377/memoqservices/tb/TBService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CommonBindingConfig" contract="TBService.ITBService" name="TBService"/>
      <endpoint address="http://mum-19377/memoqservices/FileManagerService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CommonBindingConfig" contract="FileManagerService.IFileManagerService" name="FileManagerService"/>
      <endpoint address="http://mum-19377/memoqservices/ResourceService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CommonBindingConfig" contract="ResourceService.IResourceService" name="ResourceService"/>
      <endpoint address="http://mum-19377/memoqservices/TMService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CommonBindingConfig" contract="TMService.ITMService" name="TMService"/>
      <endpoint address="http://mum-19377/memoqservices/ServerProjectService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CommonBindingConfig" contract="ServerProjectService.IServerProjectService" name="ServerProjectService"/>

      <endpoint address="https://mum-19377/memoqservices/SecurityService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="SecurityService.ISecurityService" name="SecurityService1"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>


    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: 404 Not Found... well, it's self-explained.

Answer (score 0):

You specified *mex* as the address of your metadata exchange endpoint.
So try retrieving the wsdl under some address like *https://yourServiceBaseAdress/mex* to overcome the 404.